# ASP.NET Core: "The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found" when running a Framework-Dependant app

Tags: linux, visual-studio, shell, .net-core, arm

I just installed the ASP.NET Core from [Microsoft website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1) but when i'm trying to run my app (`./Web`) i get the following error message:

```
root@stm32mp1:/usr/local/Monitoring/Web# ./Web
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.


You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=arm&rid=openstlinux-weston.3.1-openstlinux-5-4-dunfell-mp1-20-11-12-arm
```

But when i run `dotnet --list-runtimes` it tells me that the runtimes are correctly setup:

```
root@stm32mp1:/usr/local/Monitoring/Web# dotnet --list-runtimes 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Here is the result of the `dotnet --info` commad:

```
root@stm32mp1:/usr/local/Monitoring/Web# dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.100
 Commit:    cd82f021f4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     openstlinux-weston
 OS Version:  3.1-openstlinux-5-4-dunfell-mp1-20-11-12
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-arm
 Base Path:   /usr/local/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.0
  Commit:  65f04fb6db

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.100 [/usr/local/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Also my path is set correctly:

```
root@stm32mp1:/usr/local/Monitoring/Web# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/dotnet
```

I tryed with following ARM32 Binaries:

- SDK 3.1.406
- ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.12
- SDK 3.1.100
- ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.0
- Both SDK/Runtimes combined

**But nothing worked!**

For information i run this commands on and ARM32 A7 processor from STM and openstlinux-weston (which is generated from Yoctoproject)
Previously, executing this project as Framework-dependant worked, but now i can only run it as Self-Contained, but i have many project and not so much space....

Hope there is enough information to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue in the Visual studio publication process. So i started again to configure all my projects following theses steps:

Cleaned each one of my `.csproj` so the **Debug/Release configurations** looked like the following

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Release;Debug</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;Windows</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;Linux</DefineConstants>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-arm</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- ... -->
```

Redonne all the project's **publish profiles** so it looked like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>a3c8bed8-1269-4649-8573-ff4fb864100b</ProjectGuid>
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\linux-arm\publish\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-arm</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Deleted** the `/bin` and `/obj` folders. Finally **published again and it worked!**.

I renamed all my projects configurations (Release/Debug) multiple times so maybe visual studio messed up the different directories and published the wrong files to the destination Linux plateform. Hope it helps people with the same issue.